# Pros and Cons of chaining functions using lodash _.chain()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I personally avoid chaining unless its a very small set of functions.

My Team things otherwise.

[Lodash _.chain()](http://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain)

The problem that I have with using _.chain() is that if there are a lot of functions chained to it. And in the future if there are any bugs from one of these functions it takes twice the time to debug, then having small bits of functions to achieve the same.

I want to hear what the JavaScript community has to say about this.

Thanks.

Comment: bugs are bugs, chain just removes cruft

Comment: might be of interest https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba

Comment: @dandavis yes bugs are bugs for sure, but what I am trying to say is on a broad context. Reading code with is much more difficult than otherwise.

Comment: @DanielLizik yes have read that, but I find stackoverflow responses to be much more truthy and validated

Comment: i wouldn't want to save space so badly things get less readable, but at the some time, i find some chains easier to read, like a list of verbs. If you start getting bested, or conditionals, or need a few levels of indent, it might be time to break the chains (heh) into a few groups of smaller chains.

Comment: @dandavis agree strongly.

Comment: Consistency in a code base is *by far* more important than anything you've mentioned so far.

Answer (score 1):

When working with ES5.1 code, I used to be a big advocate of the `_.chain` method. It allowed for semantic flow of data using flexible methods that I could swap in and out easily. It helps to encourage immutable flow of data with collections by forcing you to write mostly pure functions.

The biggest con in my experience is the need to explicitly define what methods are allowed in the chain or implicitly rely on Lodash allowing all methods in the chain. This can cause your build to be bloated and difficult to pin down where a function in the chain comes from.

Additionally, as ECMAScript matures, I'm finding it less and less necessary to rely on Lodash for collection methods. You can accomplish a lot of what you're already using Lodash for with `filter`, `map`, `some`, `all`, `find`, `findIndex`, etc.

Another avenue worth exploring is the `_.flow` method which takes an array of callbacks and chains them together. It has a lot of the benefits of Lodash’s chaining, without the confusion of how to define the chain methods and their origin.

Comment: I might also add:

One pitfall of `_.chain` is the need to call `.chain()` when a value is desired. If you're doing that predictably, it is easy to catch, but passing around chains can lead to complex, hard to reason situations where you don't know if a chain is invoked or not.